# GET_DDL() to ERD diagrams Snowflake tool

Tags: entity-relationship, data-modeling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been looking for several days to no avail and I just want a tool to create ERD diagrams from the GET_DDL() output in Snowflake. I cannot connect directly to the database for security reasons and the ERD diagrams must be generated from the DDL only. It is completely fine if it cost money, but I cannot find a tool that accomplishes this. Thus far, I have tried:

- DBeaver (Requires live connections)
- DBSchema (Poor documentation and keeps throwing errors)
- SQLdbm (Also, throws unknown error with output)
- Visual Paradigm
- DBVisualiser

I would love to use one of the above listed tools if someone knows how to use them OR pay money for a tool that actually works. I'm just looking for any solution to this that is quick and cost less than $200 roughly to use.

Answer (score 0):

We use ER Studio by Idera for this (https://www.idera.com/er-studio-enterprise-architecture-solutions).  Unfortunately is way over your budget at around USD1400 per license.

However, it allows you to create a model by importing the DDL in a .sql file.  Initially it did not support Snowflake, and we have to make the DDL Oracle compatible (closest supported DB), but is now supports Snowflake.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the insights here. I'm surprised there is such a gap in the market space for this, but might have to end up using this. Did you find relatively good schema fidelity when you went the route of Snowflake DDL --> Oracle DDL --> ERD diagrams originally?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Oracle SQL Data Modeler? https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/datamodeler.html

It's free...

Comment: PaulHoran, it's obviously been quite some time since you posted this answer, but have you been able to implement this? (i.e. Snowflake DDL --> ERD via the Oracle SQL Data Modeler)

Answer (score 0):

You have listed DBSchema as one of the options but faced some difficulty. Below link provides complete guideline as how to use DBSchema to generate ERD for Snowflake. It uses JDBC driver to connect to Snowflake.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/DBSchema-Entity-Relationship-Diagramming-for-Snowflake